# Qual loop é mais rápido for ou foreach em C#?

Tags: c#, foreach, for

Já li artigos de algumas linguagens de programação que o loop **for** é mais rápido que o **foreach**, e queria saber se em C# tem diferenças de desempenho?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Em questão de performance o for é mais rápido, porém o foreach é mais legível.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Fiz testes iterando 10 mil vezes e outro mil vezes com tipos de dados diferentes, só pra ter uma ideia. Em todos os casos For ganhou.

Utilizei o seguinte código

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace BanchMark.ForAndForeach
{
    class Program
    {
       private static List<int> lista; 
       private static int[] array;
       private static HashSet<int> hashSet;

       static void Main(string[] args)
       {
           int qtdRegistros = 99999;
           int iterar= 10000;
           CriarCasos(qtdRegistros);
           ForeachVsFor(iterar);
           qtdRegistros = 99999;
           iterar = 1000;
           CriarCasos(qtdRegistros);
           ForeachVsFor(iterar);
           Console.ReadLine();
       }

    private static void ForeachVsFor(int repetir)
    {
        int test = 0;
        Stopwatch watch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
        for (int i = 0; i < repetir; i++)
        {
            foreach (var o in array)
            {
                test = i + i;
            }
        }
        watch.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine($"Foreach/Array {repetir} vezes: {watch.ElapsedMilliseconds}ms");

        watch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
        for (int i = 0; i < repetir ;i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < array.Length;j++)
            {
                test = i + i;
            }
        }
        watch.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine($"For/Array {repetir} vezes: {watch.ElapsedMilliseconds}ms");

        watch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
        for (int i = 0; i < repetir; i++)
        {
            foreach (var o in lista)
            {
                test = i + i;
            }
        }
        watch.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine($"Foreach/Lista {repetir} vezes: {watch.ElapsedMilliseconds}ms");

        watch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
        for (int i = 0; i < repetir; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < lista.Count; j++)
            {
                test = i + i;
            }
        }
        watch.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine($"For/Lista {repetir} vezes: {watch.ElapsedMilliseconds}ms");

        watch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
        for (int i = 0; i < repetir; i++)
        {
            foreach (var o in hashSet)
            {
                test = i + i;
            }
        }
        watch.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine($"Foreach/HashSet {repetir} vezes: {watch.ElapsedMilliseconds}ms");

        watch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
        for (int i = 0; i < repetir; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < hashSet.Count; j++)
            {
                test = i + i;
            }
        }
        watch.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine($"For/HashSet {repetir} vezes: {watch.ElapsedMilliseconds}ms");

    }

    private static void CriarCasos(int tamanho)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("***************************************");

        lista = new List<int>(tamanho);
        Random random = new Random();
        Parallel.For(1, tamanho, i =>
        {
            lista.Add(random.Next(tamanho));
        });
        array = lista.ToArray();
        hashSet = new HashSet<int>(lista);
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Esses testes não refletem inteiramente a realidade. Claro, sem ver o código utilizado nos testes, não dá para assumir muitas coisas, mas levar 4.262ms para rodar um foreach certamente tem algo bem demorado acontecendo dentro do loop, o que impede a medição mais exata do overhead e um ou outro método. Em .NET temos também que considerar o JIT: é preciso garantir que os caminhos do código já estejam compilados e otimizados pelo JIT. E, finalmente, HashSet não tem opção para ser usada com For exceto o ElementAt do LINQ e é extremamente lento! Postarei meus testes em seguida.

Comment: Qual seria o código usado para testar?

Answer (score 11):

Antes de responder de fato acho muito importante frisar que para 99,99% de todas as aplicações desenvolvidas em C# as diferenças de performance entre `for` e `foreach` não devem sequer ser levadas em consideração. É uma enorme **perda de tempo** se preocupar com esse nível de micro otimização antes de realmente provar-se necessário. A *otimização prematura é a raiz de todo o mal* na engenharia de sistemas, diria nosso poeta supremo Donald Knuth.

Dito isso, responder essa pergunta é um interessante exercício e o resultado final pode surpreender alguns. Contudo, primeiramente temos que nos ater a alguns detalhes inerentes ao .NET antes de começarmos a testar a performance das duas construções para iterações:

1. O .NET realiza otimizações apenas no build de RELEASE
2. O .NET realiza compilação em tempo de execução (JIT)
3. A quantidade de iterações deve ser grande o suficiente
4. É necessário acessar os itens em questão no código interno do loop

O item 1 é extremamente importante. Caso os testes sejam executados em modo DEBUG, o .NET não aplicará as otimizações do compilador, e isso pode transformar **completamente** os resultados dos testes. Em um artigo sobre performance de [substituição de espaços em branco em strings](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1014073/Fastest-method-to-remove-all-whitespace-from-Strin) os resultados dos testes viraram de ponta cabeça quando executados como RELEASE vs DEBUG.

O item 2 é importante, pois pode afetar negativamente o primeiro teste, ou as primeiras execuções de cada teste. O tempo de compilação do código em tempo de execução pode ser uma parte considerável da medição.

O item 3 nunca deve ser subestimado, pois com poucas iterações você pode estar medindo mais o tempo de cada instrução executada dentro do *loop* do que as diferenças de performance entre cada construção da linguagem.

O item 4 é autoexplicativo, mas importante frisar que se não forem acessados os itens dos coleções sendo varridas dentro do loop, o teste não será justo entre `for` e `foreach` pois este sempre acessa o item em questão.

---

Vamos aos resultados então! E logo para 1.000.000 (um milhão) de iterações (não foi executado o `for` do `HashSet` uma vez que a única maneira de pegar um item por índice é através do método de extensão `ElementAt` do LINQ e leva muito tempo, já que conjuntos não são indexados internamente por um índice posicional):

[image: For vs ForEach 1.000.000 de iterações]

Podemos perceber que para varrer um array quase não existe diferença entre `foreach` e `for`. Isso ocorre porque o .NET otimiza o `foreach` para arrays de tal forma que ele chega a ser mais rápido do que um `for`, já que neste acabamos precisando acessar o item do array pelo índice logo no início do loop e no `foreach` ele já vem disponível direto na construção da linguagem. A maioria das pessoas vai se surpreender com esse resultado, ainda mais se vier de outras linguagens de programação onde o `for` é uma das construções mais rápidas e quase imbatível para implementar iterações.

No caso da iteração pelos items de uma lista (um `List<Data>`) o `for` levou 60% do tempo do `foreach` para realizar a mesma operação. Isso, particularmente, me surpreendeu, pois não há muita explicação para essa diferença de tempo. Irei analisar o `IL` (código de "máquina") gerado para cada um dos métodos para tentar entender de onde toda essa diferença está vindo (e atualizarei a resposta se necessário/interessante).

Ainda assim, essa diferença é negligível (para a vasta maioria das aplicações) se considerarmos que, em 1 milhão de iterações, apenas 10ms foram adicionados ao tempo de execução.

O `HashSet`, como dito anteriormente, não pode ser testado com o `for` pois para essa quantidade de iterações tomaria muito tempo (coisa de vários minutos para cada ciclo de teste).

O código completo do programa de testes segue:

```
class Program
{
    const int MAX_TEST_DATA_LENGTH = 1000000; //1000000;
    const int MAX_FOR_HASHSET = 10000;
    static int testDataLength = MAX_TEST_DATA_LENGTH;

    static void Main(string[] args) {
        if (args.Length > 0)
            testDataLength = Convert.ToInt32(args[0]);
        Console.WriteLine("For vs ForEach Peformance\r\n");
        Console.Write(" ■ Inicializando dados de teste com {0} registros", testDataLength);
        watch.Start();
        baseData = new Data[testDataLength];
        for (int i = 0; i < testDataLength; i++) {
            baseData[i] = new Data(i);
        }
        listData = new List<Data>(baseData);
        arrayData = listData.ToArray();
        hashsetData = new HashSet<Data>(baseData);
        DisplayElapsed();

        Restart(" ■ Forçando JIT (compilação em runtime)");
        ForArray(); ForEachArray(); ForList(); ForEachList(); ForHashset(); ForEachHashset();
        DisplayElapsed();

        for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {

            Console.WriteLine("\r\n*** Ciclo {0} de teste:\r\n", i);

            // array
            Restart(" ■ For array");
            ForArray(testDataLength);
            DisplayElapsed();
            Restart(" ■ ForEach array");
            ForEachArray(testDataLength);
            DisplayElapsed();
            // List
            Restart(" ■ For List");
            ForList(testDataLength);
            DisplayElapsed();
            Restart(" ■ ForEach List");
            ForEachList(testDataLength);
            DisplayElapsed();
            // Hashset
            Restart(" ■ For HashSet");
            if (testDataLength > MAX_FOR_HASHSET) {
                Console.Write(" >>> inviável acima de {0} iterações", MAX_FOR_HASHSET);
            } else {
                ForHashset(testDataLength);
            }
            DisplayElapsed();
            Restart(" ■ ForEach HashSet");
            ForEachHashset(testDataLength);
            DisplayElapsed();

        }

        Console.WriteLine("\r\nTecle algo para encerrar");
        Console.ReadKey(true);
    }

    static Stopwatch watch = new Stopwatch();

    static Data[] baseData;
    static Data[] arrayData;
    static List<Data> listData;
    static HashSet<Data> hashsetData;

    static void Restart(string msg) {
        Console.Write(msg);
        watch.Restart();
    }

    static void DisplayElapsed() {
        var elapsed = watch.Elapsed;
        Console.WriteLine(" >>> duração: {0}ms", elapsed.TotalMilliseconds);
    }

    static void ForArray(int iterations = 10) {
        for (int i = 0; i < iterations; i++) {
            var item = arrayData[i];
            if (item.TheInt > MAX_TEST_DATA_LENGTH)
                throw new InvalidOperationException("Tamanho inválido de iterações");
        }
    }
    static void ForEachArray(int iterations = 10) {
        foreach(var item in arrayData) {
            if (item.TheInt > MAX_TEST_DATA_LENGTH)
                throw new InvalidOperationException("Tamanho inválido de iterações");
        }
    }
    static void ForList(int iterations = 10) {
        for (int i = 0; i < iterations; i++) {
            var item = listData[i];
            if (item.TheInt > MAX_TEST_DATA_LENGTH)
                throw new InvalidOperationException("Tamanho inválido de iterações");
        }
    }
    static void ForEachList(int iterations = 10) {
        foreach (var item in listData) {
            if (item.TheInt > MAX_TEST_DATA_LENGTH)
                throw new InvalidOperationException("Tamanho inválido de iterações");
        }
    }
    static void ForHashset(int iterations = 10) {
        for (int i = 0; i < iterations; i++) {
            var item = hashsetData.ElementAt(i);
            if (item.TheInt > MAX_TEST_DATA_LENGTH)
                throw new InvalidOperationException("Tamanho inválido de iterações");
        }
    }
    static void ForEachHashset(int iterations = 10) {
        foreach (var item in hashsetData) {
            if (item.TheInt > MAX_TEST_DATA_LENGTH)
                throw new InvalidOperationException("Tamanho inválido de iterações");
        }
    }

    class Data
    {
        public Data(int seed) {
            TheGuid = Guid.NewGuid();
            TheString = string.Format("{0}: {1}", seed, TheGuid);
            TheInt = seed;
            TheByteArray = new byte[1024];
        }
        public Guid TheGuid { get; set; }
        public string TheString { get; set; }
        public int TheInt { get; set; }
        public double TheDouble { get; set; }
        public byte[] TheByteArray { get; set; }
    }

}
```

*Notem que o teste dentro de cada loop é realizado apenas para garantir que o otimizador do .NET não resolva, simplesmente, "sumir" com o corpo do loop caso determina que nada esteja sendo feito dentro do mesmo.*

**Conclusão?** Acredito que dependa de cada um. Particularmente uso `foreach` sempre que não preciso saber o índice atual de uma iteração dentro do código do loop. Caso me veja fazendo coisas como `var idx = myList.IndexOf(item)` no meio de um loop eu o transformo, sem dó, em um `for`. Caso contrário esqueço até que o `for` existe! :-)

Comment: Bacana Loudenvier, ficou completo! Meu ficou muito superficial nem se compara rs

Comment: @LucasLopes na verdade se não fosse a sua resposta eu apenas teria testado com `array` e não com `List` porque tinha a impressão que a performance seria igual para ambos por causa das otimizações do .NET. Por isso que gosto de StatckOverflow mais que outros sites: cada uma das respostas contribui com algo, as vezes até mesmo as menos votadas têm algum detalhe que passou despercebido das demais! Abração

Comment: Valeu galera, todas as respostas foram muito úteis.