# O que é e como funciona a repetição do for em C#?

Tags: c#, sintaxe, for

```
for (int i = 0; i < palavra.Length; i++)
```

O que significa cada palavra? E o como funciona cada parte desse código?

Comment: `for`: laço de repetição, utilizado para repetir um trecho de código mais de 1 vez. `int i = 0`: declaração de uma variavel inteira. `i < palavra.legth`: vai percorrer de 0 ao tamanho da palavra. `i++`: incrementa 1 ao valor de i

Comment: https://www.dotnetperls.com/for

Comment: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/158379/64969

Comment: Só pra constar, votei "ampla" apesar do fechamento como "não clara". Pra quem não conhece o sistema do site, o voto de fechamento é "generalizado" no final.

Comment: @Bacco Porquê "ampla"?

Comment: @ramaral por tratar de vários conceitos num mesmo trecho de código (estrutura de repetição, declaração de variável, escopo, incremento, método de string, só pra começar). Note que não sou contra o autor receber a devida explicação, porém não entendo que deva ser o tipo de pergunta "aberta" no site, por falta de especificidade e foco. Entendo que já foi resolvida com o "resumo" do bigown (para o autor entender mais profundamente teria que detalhar mil coisas mais). O que poderia ser o caso de um fechamento por motivo personalizado em vez de um "ampla", mas fui pelo caminho econômico.

Comment: @ramaral notar que o título foi [alterado **depois** do fechamento](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/237601/revisions) , e nem sei se realmente representa a intenção original do autor. Inclusive pq aí acho que até pode ser duplicata

Comment: @Bacco Não concordo totalmente com você, mas essa questão da edição, realmente ela não apresenta a intenção do autor. Deveria ser revertida.

Comment: @Bacco Obrigado, não tinha reparado na edição.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Isto é o início de um laço de repetição com uma inicialização, uma condição que indica o término do laço e um passo que deve ser executado em cada interação.

```
for ()
```

É a palavra chave que indica ao compilador que é um laço de repetição neste formato descrito acima. Ele obrigatoriamente terá as 3 partes entre parênteses

```
int i = 0;
```

Aqui imagino que já conheça, está declarando uma variável do tipo inteiro chamada `i` e atribuindo 0 a ela. Isso ocorre apenas uma vez no início. Essa variável só existirá dentro do bloco do `for`.

```
i < palavra.Length;
```

Aqui é a condição, igual colocaria em um `if`. Enquanto essa expressão resultar em `true` o laço continuará executando o seu bloco de código em repetições sucessivas. No caso a condição verifica se `i` vale menos que o tamanho da variável `palavra` que deve ser uma coleção de dados (*array*, ou `List`, ou `string`, o mais provável, ou algo assim). Quando bater o valor de `i` com o tamanho, significa que percorreu toda coleção de dados.

```
i++
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Syntax/ForExplained.cs).

Aqui está incrementando em 1 a variável `i`, que é a ação mais comum de um `for`, sempre ir andando de 1 em 1, mas pode usar qualquer ação que faça sentido aí. Então em cada passo do laço a variável vai tendo seu valor alterado com a próxima unidade. Provavelmente dentro dele a variável será usada para acessar o elemento específico da coleção de dados. A varredura será completa já que começa no 0 e termina no seu tamanho.

Leia mais:

- [Não consigo aprender sintaxe for](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/33674/101)
- [For com um ";" no começo do laço, o que significa](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/174153/101)

Comment: Muito obrigado ajudou muito agradeço.